# Setting path of krb5.conf in Tomcat Application

Tags: java, tomcat, kerberos

We have a Java Web Application, which used Hadoop cluster for storage.
The cluster is kerberos enabled.

By default, our application reads the krb5.conf file from /etc folder.
We want that the krb5.conf file to be read from user specific location.

KRB5_CONFIG=/path_of_krb5_conf_file is already set in bashrc file.

Can anyone please help in this regards?

Do I need to add something in server.xml or web.xml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy your custom krb5.conf to $CATALINA_BASE/conf/ which might work.  If that doesn't work, the location of the krb5.conf your Java web application uses can be changed by setting the java.security.krb5.conf JVM property:

```
java -Djava.security.krb5.conf=/path/to/custom/krb5.conf
```

Reference: [Configuring Tomcat 7 Single Sign-on with SPNEGO (Kerberos & LDAP)](http://janbernhardt.blogspot.com/2017/02/kerberos-debugging-in-java.html)